# Creating aliases in PowerShell for git commands?

Tags: git, powershell

I understand how to create aliases in PowerShell for cmdlets fine, but I want to create an alias in PowerShell for things like `git status` as just `gs`, and `git pull origin master` as `gpm`. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You will have to create a function first, that has your command in it. Then create an alias to that function.

```
PS C:\Users\jpogran\code\git\scripts> function get-gitstatus { git status }

PS C:\Users\jpogran\code\git\scripts> get-gitstatus
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

PS C:\Users\jpogran\code\git\scripts> Set-Alias -Name gs -Value get-gitstatus

PS C:\Users\jpogran\code\git\scripts> gs
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

You might also be interested in the OS project called [posh-git](http://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) that aims to provide a powershell environment for git commands. Wraps git commands with PS type functions and also provides a new prompt that shows the status and branch in your prompt.

EDIT: Forgot to add how to find out how to do this using Powershell.

```
PS C:\Users\jpogran\code\git\scripts> get-help set-alias -examples
```

This will show you examples (the last one applies here) of how to use set-alias to create aliases to commands with paramaters, pipelines, etc.

Comment: Bonus points for adding the git functions+aliases in a standalone script, and having them sourced in from your profile.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849938.aspx#sectionSection8 for the online examples :)

Comment: If you define your own `Get-GitStatus` function as above, you'll overwrite posh-git's `Get-GitStatus` which is used to get structured status info to build the custom prompt.

Comment: Why another alias when you got a function? Just put a short function name as @alex does with the posh kid ähh git.

Answer (score 81):

Just created some shortcuts for myself and wanted to share:

Create a PowerShell profile (if you don't already have one):

```
New-Item -Type file -Path $PROFILE -Force
```

Open it to edit:

```
notepad $PROFILE
```

Add the following functions and aliases:

```
function Get-GitStatus { & git status $args }
New-Alias -Name s -Value Get-GitStatus
function Set-GitCommit { & git commit -am $args }
New-Alias -Name c -Value Set-GitCommit
```

When you restart your PowerShell session, you should be able to pass arguments to the aliases as well. e.g.:

```
c "This is a commit message"
```

Update:

Here are some more of my frequently-used shortcuts:

```
function Get-GitStatus { & git status -sb $args }
New-Alias -Name s -Value Get-GitStatus -Force -Option AllScope
function Get-GitCommit { & git commit -ev $args }
New-Alias -Name c -Value Get-GitCommit -Force -Option AllScope
function Get-GitAdd { & git add --all $args }
New-Alias -Name ga -Value Get-GitAdd -Force -Option AllScope
function Get-GitTree { & git log --graph --oneline --decorate $args }
New-Alias -Name t -Value Get-GitTree -Force -Option AllScope
function Get-GitPush { & git push $args }
New-Alias -Name gps -Value Get-GitPush -Force -Option AllScope
function Get-GitPull { & git pull $args }
New-Alias -Name gpl -Value Get-GitPull -Force -Option AllScope
function Get-GitFetch { & git fetch $args }
New-Alias -Name f -Value Get-GitFetch -Force -Option AllScope
function Get-GitCheckout { & git checkout $args }
New-Alias -Name co -Value Get-GitCheckout -Force -Option AllScope
function Get-GitBranch { & git branch $args }
New-Alias -Name b -Value Get-GitBranch -Force -Option AllScope
function Get-GitRemote { & git remote -v $args }
New-Alias -Name r -Value Get-GitRemote -Force -Option AllScope
```

Comment: What does the & do?

Comment: @MattW The ampersand operator forces PowerShell to execute the following arguments as a command (CMD). It may not always be required, but I found it avoids any unintended effects that could result from arguments injected at the end of the command ($args) being evaluated incorrectly.

Comment: You don't actually need aliases anymore in this case. You can just name your function e.g. `s` and then call it directly as a command.

Comment: It should be noted that `Get-GitStatus` already exists (at least it did in my quite simple Win11/VisualStudio machine. That `Get-GitStatus` is something different and will, for good and bad, be overwritten by the above code.

Answer (score 13):

I created [posh-git-alias](https://github.com/AlexZeitler/posh-git-alias) which you can just add to your PowerShell `$PROFILE`.

Comment: Thanks for those!  Very useful to me.

Comment: 5 years later still up to date. You should rename the list to posh git functions ...

Answer (score 11):

I don't know PowerShell, but you can [setup aliases directly in Git](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases).

Comment: The above link didn't work for me.  this link provides similar info https://git.wiki.kernel.org/articles/a/l/i/Aliases.html

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a profile.ps1 file put it in a folder call WindowsPowerShell in my documents

Then put in profile.ps1 a line like this:

```
set-alias wit 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\witadmin.exe'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create PowerShell profile that autorun when open PowerShell
First open PowerShell and create PowerShell profile (If you don't already have one):

> `New-Item -Type file -Path $PROFILE -Force`

This command will create directory in Documents call **`WindowsPowerShell`** inside this directory will create file call **`Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`**

If you want to know the full path of **`Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`** write this command:

> **`$PROFILE`**

Open it from PowerShell with this command

> **`powershell_ise.exe $PROFILE`**

And write all commands that you want to alias it for example:

```bash
function gn{git init}
# @args you can pass multi arguments for example
# ga fileName1 fileName2 
function add{git add @args}
function commit { git commit -m @args }
function gac{git add .;git commit -m @args}
function gpm{git push origin master}
function pull{git pull origin master}
function gl{git log}
function glo{git log --oneline}
function gch{git checkout @args}

# @args is optional to add argument
function gb{git branch @args}
function gs{git status}
function gd{git diff}
```

Save it And close PowerShell, Open it again and call alias commands by function name for example initialize git repository write this command:

> `gn`

To add files write this commands

> `add fileName1`

See GIF image
[image: aliases git commands from PowerShell]

To show content of alias commands write this command:

> `Get-Content $PROFILE`

Answer (score 0):

If you use [PowerShell](https://microsoft.com/PowerShell), then you need to add functions including the commands that you want to create the alias for.

For example, you want to create an alias for `git fetch -all`, then you need to add the following in the file `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile`:

```
function gfa{git fetch --all}
```

Then if you run `gfa` in your [PowerShell](https://microsoft.com/PowerShell) or [WindowsTerminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal), then `git fetch --all` will be executed.

**Note**: To open `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile` file in your notepad, run `notepad $profile` in your [PowerShell](https://microsoft.com/PowerShell) or [WindowsTerminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal). Or you navigate to `C:\Users\YOUR_USER\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` to get the file.

Here is a list of common functions:

```bash
function gs{git status}
function ga{git add .}
function gfa{git fetch --all}

function grman{git rebase -i main}
function grmas{git rebase -i master}
function grdev{git rebase -i develop}

function gitc{ git commit -m @args }
function gac{git add .;git commit -m @args}
function pushmas{git push origin master}
function pushman{git push origin main}
function pushdev{git push origin develop}

function pullman{git pull origin main}
function pullmas{git pull origin main}
function pulldev{git pull origin develop}

function pull{git pull origin master}
function gl{git log}
function glo{git log --oneline}
function gch{git checkout @args}
function gcn{git checkout -b @args}

function gman{git checkout main}
function gmas{git checkout master}
function gdev{git checkout develop}

function gb{git branch @args}
function gs{git status}
function gd{git diff}
```

This [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/mushfiqweb) is the [link to my own](https://gist.github.com/mushfiqweb/b0fbffcbdeef9e5c3199af987934edae) `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late for this question, but for anyone who still has similar question, install this [powershell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/git-aliases/0.3.5):

```
PS> Install-Module -Name git-aliases
```

According to it's description,

> A PowerShell module that provide partial Git aliases from Oh My Zsh's git plugin.

Answer (score -1):

On Windows, I use the following content in a `.gitconfig` file located in the user home folder:

```
[alias]
  co = checkout
  ci = commit
  st = status
  sw = switch
  d  = diff
  hist = log --pretty=format:\"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]\" --graph --date=short
  type = cat-file -t
  dump = cat-file -p
```