# Creating persistent PHPStorm command line aliases in Windows

Tags: windows, phpstorm

Having to retype "php artisan migrate:refresh --seed" for Laravel (amongst many other commands) in PHPStorm is getting real old.

On Mac or Linux, this is easily rectified with an `alias` command. Alas, I am on Windows, which uses `doskey` to assign aliases and it does not persist across sessions.

How can I create an alias persistently under Windows 8+? Or simply a way to have certain commands executed on PHPStorm launch so they automatically create the command alias list?

Comment: **1)** You can use `Command Line Tool Support` to have such aliases. The bad thing: they will only work in actual `Command Line Tool Support` tool window (available under `Tools | Run Command`) but not actual `Terminal` tool window

Comment: **2)** For *"`doskey` to assign aliases"* -- create (edit original) `autoexec.bat` (or .cmd) which gets executed when you launch terminal (cmd.exe). As alternative -- you could try to use such .bat/.cmd file instead in Terminal settings instead of `cmd.exe` -- such batch file will create all aliases and launch actual cmd.exe for you.

Comment: **3)** Yet another option -- use **poweshell shell** instead of cmd.exe in your Terminal tool window -- it supports aliases.

Comment: Tried using powershell but can't seem to create aliases for standard commands. They seem to only work when referencing cmdlets.

Comment: I had a strong impression that PS could do that. Possibly some 3rd party extension was used for that (I have seen it working fine on my friend's computer; and I've checked that PS has "set-alias" command .. which I was expecting to work just like that). My mistake and apologies then.

Comment: **On a second thought:** Such "complex" stuff could possible be implemented differently (not as "alias" but as a "function") -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858484/creating-aliases-in-powershell-for-git-commands